# Conditional expectation of joint probability conditional of sigma algebra

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I was asked to proof the following property:

Let X be $\mathcal{G}$ -measurable and let Y be independent of $\mathcal{G}$.

Let $\mathcal{f}$ (x, y) be a bounded continuous function and define $\mathcal{g}$(x) = E[ $\mathcal{f}$( x , Y )  ].

Show that E[ $\mathcal{f}$( X, Y ) | G] = $\mathcal{g}$(X).

I can see how it's true for function of the form f(x,y)=p(x)q(y),but I don't know what to do for the general case. 
Could someone please give me some hint on this? Been stuck on it for a long time.

Answer (score 1):

Since $g(X)$ is $\mathcal{G}$-measurable (and presumably integrable), we just need to check that
$$
\int_A g(X)\,\mathrm dP=\int_A f(X,Y)\,\mathrm dP,\quad A\in\mathcal{G}.
$$
By linearity, we can assume that $f$ is non-negative. For $A\in\mathcal{G}$, we let $Z=\mathbf{1}_A$. Now
$$
\begin{align}
\int_A g(X)\,\mathrm dP&=\int g(X)Z\,\mathrm dP=\int g(x)z\,P_{X,Z}(\mathrm dx,\mathrm dz)\\
&=\int\Big(\int f(x,y)z\,P_Y(\mathrm dy)\Big)\,P_{X,Z}(\mathrm dx,\mathrm dz)\\
&=\int f(x,y)z \,P_{X,Z,Y}(\mathrm dx,\mathrm dz,\mathrm dy)\\
&=\int f(X,Y)Z\,\mathrm dP=\int_A f(X,Y)\,\mathrm dP,
\end{align}
$$
where we have used the independence assumption to conclude that $P_{X,Z}\times P_Y=P_{X,Z,Y}$

Comment: I'm sorry, but what does P_Y(dy) represent?

Comment: @SunkenS: Integration with respect to the distribution of $Y$, that is, the measure defined by $P_Y(A)=P(Y^{-1}(A))$.

Comment: Ok. Thank you, that was very helpful